# how to acess model attribute inside strapi model lifecycle methods

Tags: strapi

I have Post Api and I want to access title of my post inside Post.js (model) beforeFetch(...) method.

[image]

I tried all my best but I coudn't find any way to achieve this.

NOTE: I am new to nodejs world, but I found this Strapi cms a bit promising, so thought to give a try.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Hello! I don't understand why you want to access to your data before the fetch action... You are before, so it mean you haven't the data.
It's mean you don't have the data at this time.

Comment: so say, if I want to modify or add some of my own data before inserting/updaing my model or even after fetching the model. in this scenario, how can I achieve this, what do you suggest

Answer (score 1):

Life cycle are not currently the best way to do this type of things cause it's the integration of the ORM function and the context is not the best for Strapi.

I suggest you to update add/fetch/edit services functions to do your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Strapi Beta now and this is what I'm doing...

Say you have the following model **User** fetched:

```
{
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "padding": "dummy"
}
```

Then you can do something in **afterFetch**() like:

```
// Add some fields:
model.set('phone', '0439283746');
// Delete some fields:
model.unset('padding');
```

Basically (I assume) the **model** object is a **Bookshelf Model** which means you can find all the methods from [here.](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model)